# Spark Launcher: Can't see the complete stack trace for failed SQL query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-launcher

I'm using `SparkLauncher` to connect to Spark in cluster mode on top of Yarn. I'm running some SQL code using Scala like this:

```
def execute(code: String): Unit = {
    try {
      val resultDataframe = spark.sql(code)
      resultDataframe.write.json("s3://some/prefix")
    catch {
      case NonFatal(f) =>
        log.warn(s"Fail to execute query $code", f)
        log.info(f.getMessage, getNestedStackTrace(f, Seq[String]()))
    } 
}

def getNestedStackTrace(e: Throwable, msg: Seq[String]): Seq[String] = {
   if (e.getCause == null) return msg
   getNestedStackTrace(e.getCause, msg ++ e.getStackTrace.map(_.toString))
}
```

Now when I run a query that should fail with the `execute()` method, for example, querying a partitioned table without a partitioned predicate - `select * from partitioned_table_on_dt limit 1;`, I get an incorrect stack trace back.

**Correct stack trace when I run spark.sql(code).write.json() manually from spark-shell:**

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange SinglePartition
+- *(1) LocalLimit 1
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.doExecute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
...

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: No partition predicate found for partitioned table
 partitioned_table_on_dt.
 If the table is cached in memory then turn off this check by setting
 hive.mapred.mode to nonstrict
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveTableScanExec.prunePartitions(HiveTableScanExec.scala:155)
...

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
...
```

**Incorrect stack trace from the execute() method above:**

```
Job Aborted: 
"org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)",
"org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)",
"org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)",
"org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)",
...

"org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)",
"org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.doExecute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)",
"org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)",
"org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)",
...
```

The spark-shell stack trace has three nested exceptions `SparkException`(`SemanticException` (`TreeNodeException`)) but the traceback that I'm seeing with my code is only from the `SparkException` and `TreeNodeException` but the most valuable `SemanticException` traceback is missing even after fetching the nested stack traces in the `getNestedStackTrace()` method.

Can any Spark/Scala experts tell me what am I doing wrong or how do I fetch the complete stack trace here with all the exceptions?

Comment: check executor logs on yarn? you will get the cause of failure there. Also, I think, SparkLauncher only shows driver stacktrace

Comment: what is code ?? & can you post value for code ??

Comment: can you try without NonFatal in catch block ?? to get more details on exception ??

Comment: @SomeshwarKale the stack traces I shared in the post are from the driver. SparkLauncher does pull only the driver logs but it is missing stack trace information via my code snippet.

Comment: @Srinivas code is the actual query string. It is `select * from partitioned_table_on_dt limit 1` for the stack traces above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursive method `getNestedStackTrace()` had a bug.

```
def getNestedStackTrace(e: Throwable, msg: Seq[String]): Seq[String] = {
   if (e == null) return msg // this should be e not e.getCause  
   getNestedStackTrace(e.getCause, msg ++ e.getStackTrace.map(_.toString))
}
```